# UIAPickerWheel.selectValue() not working for text values within UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I have created a simple project using storyboards containing just a UIDatePicker with mode=Date (so that dates appear like "November" "28" "2011").

Within Instruments UI Automation I am trying to set the values of the individual date picker wheels.

I can successfully use the selectValue() method to set the wheels which contains numeric values but cannot manage to set text value of the month e.g. "November".

This works..

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0].wheels()[1].selectValue(12);
```

but this doesn't..

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0].wheels()[0].selectValue("November");
```

I get the error: `Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: - selectValue is not supported on a picker with undefined values`

I have done a `UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().logElementTree()` and can see the value is correct:

UIAPickerWheel: value:November rect:{{1, 142}, {146, 216}}

Please can anyone advise on what I might be doing wrong, many thanks.

Comment: did you make any progress here ?

Answer (score 4):

This has been remedied in the latest version of xcode (4.5.2)

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0].wheels()[0].selectValue("November");
```

It will now work.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(monthWheel.value() != "June"){
  monthWheel.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.33}});
  target.delay(0.5);
}
```

value is not variable, it is a function so you should call `value()` on month wheel like I used.
and `tapWithOptions()` will take you to next row in the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I would tap until my value is the one I want.  Since the value set is 12 months, it'll roll around.

```
while(target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0].wheels()[0].value != "November"){
  target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0].wheels()[0].tap();
}
```

Comment: Hi good idea but this doesn't work - when I try this I just get stuck in an infinite loop and the wheel doesn't roll on :-(

Comment: while(monthWheel.value != "June"){
  monthWheel.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.33}});  
  monthWheel.logElementTree();
  target.delay(0.5);
}  though monthWheel.value is still not returning a valid result

Answer (score 0):

Just find all the values of the particular picker wheel using

```
var pickerWheel1Values  = picker.wheels()[1]. values();
```

and if you want to set November just do

```
picker.wheels()[index]. selectValue (pickerWheel1Values[10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Appium see this page here on the discussion board: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appium-discuss/uYdRTdQDvpU/2I7KSFHnqFwJ

The flow goes like this:

- get your picker element (tag name: picker)
- get all the wheels for that picker (tag name: pickerwheel)
- you can list values for that wheel by doing element.getAttribute("values")
- you can set the value by doing element.setValue(myNewValue)

The last step is wrong and you need to use sendKeys() instead of setValue()

For a real example like how I used it would be something like this

```
String pickerWheelLocation = "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[3].pickers()[0].elements()[0]"
By pickerWheelBy = MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(pickerWheelLocation)
IOSElement pickerWheel = WebDriverHelper.getDriver().findElement(pickerWheelBy);
pickerWheel.sendKeys("New Value");

IOSElement doneButton = WebDriverHelper.getDriver().findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().windows()[2].toolbars()[0].buttons()["Done"]"));
    doneButton.click();
```